# Redirect if user is not an admin is not working on SSL

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been using the code below for a while with no trouble. I redirect back to the main page if user is not an admin. I just installed SSL and now does not work anymore. I know it has something to do with the code checking for SSL but I'm not sure how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

```
function redirect_admin_login()
{
    global $wpdb;
    global $current_user;
    $visitor = $current_user->ID;
    $login_page = home_url('');
    $page_viewed = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if ($page_viewed == "wp-admin" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && $visitor != '1')
    {
        wp_redirect($login_page);
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('init', 'redirect_admin_login');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following code a shot

```
function admin_redirect()
{
    if (!current_user_can('administrator') && (!defined('DOING_AJAX') || !DOING_AJAX ))
    {
        wp_safe_redirect(get_home_url());
        exit();
    }
}

add_action('admin_init', 'admin_redirect', 1);
```